# How to inject HttpHeader in Aspect class

Tags: logging, cdi, aspectj, inject

I'm trying to inject `HttpHeader` in the aspect class.

This is the code:

```java
public aspect RestRequestsAspect {

    @Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders;

    @Before("endPointsInterfacesCut() || servicesCut() || patternCrudCut()")
    public void beforeCreate(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        printLogTrace(joinPoint);
    }

    private void printLogTrace(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        if (this.httpHeaders != null)
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName()).info(httpHeaders.toString());
    }
}
```

It logs nothing, so the `HttpHeader` must be null.

What does the CDI need to inject the `HttpHeader` into the aspect?

Comment: Your conclusion could be incorrect. Maybe it logs nothing because the aspect is not triggered at all. First you should always log something such as `thisJoinPoint`, just to make sure that the aspect is triggered as expected.

Comment: I've tested it and works correctly, but httpheader prints nothing.

Comment: Then you probably have a CDI problem rather than an AspectJ problem. I can only help you concerning the latter. BTW, sorry for the late answer, I was on vacation for 3 weeks.